# PDFBox : NullPointerException in StandardSecurityHandler.java

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have a encrypted PDF Form document, where need to fill in the forms with desired value  and at last need to save the document 
Here is my piece of code of what I tried

```
            PDDocument document;
            document = PDDocument.load(sourcePath);
            if( document.isEncrypted() )
            {
                try
                {
                    document.decrypt( "" );
                }
                catch( InvalidPasswordException e )
                {

                }
            }
            PDAcroForm form = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
            PDField Field_1= form.getField("topmostSubform[0].CMS1500Form[0].PatientName[0]");          
            Field_1.setValue("ABC");    
            document.save("C:\\Users\\347702\\Desktop\\21.pdf");
            document.close();
```

But it throws me the below exception

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.StandardSecurityHandler.prepareDocumentForEncryption(StandardSecurityHandler.java:303)

I have also tried with adding the below statement,  above doc.save("");

```
document.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
```

Now I can execute the program without any errors but the desired value (Value : "ABC") is not been filled in saved document .. it looks blank

Can anyone help me out please !!

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the PDF for inspection?

Comment: @mkl : yeah sure can u pls provide any me your email ID

Comment: Is it not possible to provide it via Dropbox or something similar? I assume others (e.g. plinth who already did some source code lookup in his answer) could also help better having such a sample.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the code for StandardSecurityHandler.java, which is [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/encryption/StandardSecurityHandler.java).  Inside this method, we see the following code:

```
    version = computeVersionNumber();
    revision = computeRevisionNumber();
    encryptionDictionary.setFilter(FILTER);
    encryptionDictionary.setVersion(version);
    encryptionDictionary.setRevision(revision);
    encryptionDictionary.setLength(keyLength);

    String ownerPassword = policy.getOwnerPassword();
    String userPassword = policy.getUserPassword();
```

Allowing that the version we're looking at might not be the same as yours, the most likely cause is that the policy object is null (which is line 305, not 303, but that's the first line after this where this **could** fail from a NullPointerException.

Now as to form fields not being filled in, you should save with no encryption and look for the string `(PatientName[0])`, which should be the field name of the field you're trying to edit.  If you find it, you should check to see if the dictionary contains the key `/V` with the associated value `(ABC)`, which means that the code correctly set the field.  If this is the case, I'm willing to bet that your document also has XFA in it, which means that the actual data for the form may not necessarily be stored in the form, but may also need to be stored in an XFA data packet.  The good news is that the XFA spec is available from Adobe.  The bad news is that the XFA spec is 1500 pages.  The good news is that XFA is a big suite of XML nodes with a downloadable schema.  The bad news is the schema is not a typical standard format and the available tools for consuming it are (apparently) unmaintained.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable response.. I tried by entering getfield(PatientName[0]). But yet again it throws Null pointer exception on setValue("ABC")..

Comment: I could also see dictionary key and it associated Value ("ABC") but it fails to save it .. can u please guide me to move further pls

Comment: No, I really can't help you further - use process of elimination to find where it's going wrong - standard debugging, really.